Why a string assignment operation result in double memory usage in perl
When I executed the following perl code on the command line with a -e option,
$s=q(top -bn1 -p $PPID); system $s; $v="\0"x(2*1024**3); print"\n"x3; system $s

Its output may look like this,
$ perl -e '$s=q(top -bn1 -p $PPID); system $s; $v="\0"x(2*1024**3); print"\n"x3;system $s'

top - 20:11:27 up 5 days,  4:10,  1 user,  load average: 0.24, 0.10, 0.08
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7937.6 total,   3065.8 free,   4144.2 used,    727.6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,     87.8 free,   1960.2 used.   3433.7 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
4133828 sam       20   0 2110500   2.0g   4712 S   0.0  25.9   0:02.35 perl



top - 20:11:31 up 5 days,  4:10,  1 user,  load average: 0.30, 0.11, 0.09
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7937.6 total,   1029.3 free,   6180.7 used,    727.6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,     87.8 free,   1960.2 used.   1397.2 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
4133828 sam       20   0 4207656   4.0g   4712 S   0.0  51.7   0:06.17 perl


I found it first used about 2.0g in RES before assignment and then 4.0g.
If executing a simple top command in perl,
$ perl -e 'system "top -bn1 -p $PPID"'
top: -p requires argument

$ perl -e 'system "top -bn1 -p \$PPID"'
top - 20:27:18 up 5 days,  4:26,  1 user,  load average: 0.13, 0.17, 0.13
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.6 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7937.6 total,   4600.3 free,   2081.7 used,   1255.6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,     89.0 free,   1959.0 used.   5496.1 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
4142493 sam       20   0   13344   3664   3384 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 perl

it used 3664 kB (perl -E 'say 3664/1024' => 3.578125) in RES.
Other
$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 0 (v5.30.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 60 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2019, Larry Wall
...


Are you sure it's the string assignment and not the fork and exec for the system calls?

Due to constant folding, "\0"x(2*1024**3) creates a 2 GiB string at compile-time.
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'$v = "\0" x 6;'
1  <0> enter v
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <$> const[PV "\000\000\000\000\000\000"] s/FOLD
4  <#> gvsv[*v] s
5  <2> sassign vKS/2
6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK

(I'm using shorter strings in my examples, but I confirmed the same behaviour happens for "\0"x(2*1024**2).)
Assigning a string normally uses no memory thanks to the Copy-on-Write ("COW") mechanism.
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'$v = "abcdef"; Dump($v);'
SV = PV(0x55cb5eec3f20) at 0x55cb5eef32e0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)              <--- Copy avoided thanks to COW.
  PV = 0x55cb5ef3aaf0 "abcdef"\0
  CUR = 6
  LEN = 16
  COW_REFCNT = 1

However, the COW mechanism doesn't appear to be used for folded constants.
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'$v = "abc"."def"; Dump($v);'
SV = PV(0x5632e85d3f20) at 0x5632e86030d0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)                    <--- String buffer isn't shared.
  PV = 0x5632e85ef540 "abcdef"\0
  CUR = 6
  LEN = 16

$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'$v = "\0" x 6; Dump($v);'
SV = PV(0x555a533d3f20) at 0x555a534031e0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)                    <--- String buffer isn't shared.
  PV = 0x555a533ef540 "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"\0
  CUR = 6
  LEN = 16

Therefore, $v = "\0"x(2*1024**3); creates a copy of the string.
This is a bug that has now been fixed in upcoming 5.42.

Do you think that the lack of COW for constant-folded strings is by design? It feels a bit wasteful.

@Dada, See addition at the bottom.

Cool, thanks :) "To hide the fact that constant folding occurs" --> I don't think that this behavior is hiding anything: initial memory consumption is much higher than anticipated because of the constant folding. Also, in general, COW can be observed by monitoring memory usage (and I'd argue that most optimizations are bound to change either memory usage or execution time, neither of which should really count as user-observable behavior).

@Dada, While the amount of extra memory usage may be considered a factor in deciding whether to add an optimization or not, the mere fact that there is a difference in memory usage is not.

Is that Perl's official stance? That's a bit surprising imo, and definitely not shared by all programming languages / compilers. For instance, using String pools is a frequent optimization and has mainly memory benefits rather than performance ones. Similarly, doing compaction in garbage collectors is an optimization whose main benefit is reducing memory. And, in general, reducing memory reduces the number of allocations, which improves performance, so it's a bit hard to say whether optimizations are done for memory or performance reasons, but things like NaN boxing are probably done for both.

@Dada Re "That's a bit surprising imo, and definitely not shared by all programming languages / compilers", It absolutely is. Optimizations tend to change the amount of time and memory used (and not always for the better in all cases). For example, a decent C compiler will optimize int i=0; for (int j=0; j<10; ++j) ++i; f(i) into f(10), reducing both time and memory used. And the same compiler might unroll some loops to increase performance at the cost of space. It makes no sense to preserve every aspect of the unoptimized behaviour, since that would defy the purpose of the optimization.

Ah, I probably interpreted your previous comment wrong and thought that you were saying that compilers don't do optimizations that "just reduce memory usage", but given your last comment, it doesn't seem that it's what you meant. \n I still don't think that not doing COW to hide constant folding doesn't make much sense, but that's not really important :)

@Dada, It was in reply to your comment stating that memory usage wasn't conserved by the optimization

Not using COW for folded constants was a bug that has just been fixed in blead with v5.41.0-13-g06e421c559.
